# Calculus 2 showing Improper Integral Converges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

[image]

I clearly know this converges.  I'm however having trouble showing it by comparison.  I need to show it is less than some convergent integral so I need to somehow make the denominator smaller but I'm having trouble doing this. I tried $x^4-2x^2+1$ for denominator, which factors $(x^2-1)*(x^2-1)$ .  But this doesn't really do anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $$\int_{0}^\infty= \int_{0}^2 + \int_{2}^\infty$$ and$$x^4-x^2+1>x^4-x^2$$ thus

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4-x^2+1}dx \leq \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4-x^2} dx=\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx$$

Comment: there is a pole at $x = 1$, and how can you deal with it ?

Comment: of course, you are absolutely right, I've corrected my hint :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you decide to split it up specifically into (0,2) and (2,infinity)?

Comment: to avoid the point x=1 that's so bad for $1/(x^2-1)$but you can choose any other number >1 if you prefer :)

Answer (score 2):

We have : $\int_{0}^\infty= \int_{0}^1 + \int_{1}^\infty$ and compare the second term of the sum with $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}$ and the first term is less than $\int_{0}^1\frac{4x^2}{3} $ ( since $x^4-x^2+1 > \frac{3}{4}$ ),and these imply convergence.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with just simple comparison?  I don't really understand what you are doing.